# subst Y: says invalid parameter when assigning drive letter

Tags: subst

Tried to assign virtual drive to a long path as drive `Y:\` with `subst Y:` in cmd prompt as admin privileges, but it says `invalid parameter Y:`. I checked with `wmic logicaldisk get name` but it has not been used. Why I can't assign it?

Comment: One possibility: the target path does not exist.